# Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Vendor\Modulename\Block\Sales\Order\Items:::isPagerDisplayed

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3.p1

I am going to add some data content in Order Items at the Frontend.I am using Magento 2.4.3

I have given preference in the **di.xml** file

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" type="Vendor\CustomName\Sales\Block\Order\Items" />
```

And Added a plugin :

```
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items">
        <plugin name="CQC_Serialcodes::getItemHtml" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Items" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
```

I am overriding **Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer**

> Block layout

Item.php file :

> Path : app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Sales\Order\Items.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Sales order view items block
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Sales\Order;

use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data as helper;
use Vendor\Module\Model\SerialcodeFactory as SerialcodeModelFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository as ProductRepositoryModel;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper as escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as jsonHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Block\Items\AbstractItems;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory as ItemFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

/**
 * Shipping Items Block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Items extends AbstractItems
{
    protected $_productRepository;
    
    //protected $_jsonSerializer;

    /**
     * @var jsonHelper
     */
    protected $jsonHelper;

    protected $itemFactory;

    protected $orderCollection;

    protected $helper;

    protected $serialcodeModelFactory;

    protected $registry;

    /**
     * Escaper
     *
     * @var escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryModel $productRepository,
        jsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        ItemFactory $itemFactory,
        CollectionFactory $orderCollection,
        SerialcodeModelFactory $serialcodeModelFactory,
        escaper $_escaper,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        helper $helper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
            $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
            $this->itemFactory =$itemFactory;
            $this->orderCollection=$orderCollection;
            $this->serialcodeModelFactory = $serialcodeModelFactory;
            $this->_escaper=$_escaper;
            $this->helper = $helper;
            $this->registry = $registry;

            parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param DataObject $item
     * @return array|string|string[]
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getItemHtml(DataObject $item)
    {
        $html = "getItemHtml called";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

> Plugin File :  app\code\Vendor\Module\Plugin\Items.php

```
 <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Vendor\Module\Model\SerialcodeFactory as SerialcodeModelFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository as ProductRepositoryModel;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Block\Items\AbstractItems;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

/**
 *
 */
class Items extends AbstractItems
{
    protected $orderCollection;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $serialcodeModelFactory;
    protected $itemFactory;
    protected $order;
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context                $context,
        ProductRepositoryModel $productRepository,
        SerialcodeModelFactory        $serialcodeModelFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        CollectionFactory      $orderCollection,
        ItemFactory            $itemFactory,
        OrderInterface         $order,
        array                  $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->serialcodeModelFactory = $serialcodeModelFactory;
        $this->orderCollection = $orderCollection;
        $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->registry = $registry;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param DataObject $item
     * @param array|string|string[] $result
     * @return array|string|string[]
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterGetItemHtml(DataObject $item, $result)
    {
        $html1 = "after success";
        return $html1;
    }
}
```

[image]

The Output Will be like below screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one method, plugin or override. In this case this function is public so you can use plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items">
        <plugin name="CQC_Serialcodes::getItemHtml" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Items" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
```

And PHP File

```
public function afterGetItemHtml(DataObject $item, $result)
    {
        $html1 = "after success";
        return $html1;
    }
```